# AngularJS compose a dynamic variable in the html

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of items from a DB, there are different columns in the DB and two of them have a value of the item in Italian and the other one in English.

Specifically:

```
---------------------
 value_it | value_en
---------------------
 Uno      | One
---------------------
 Due      | Two
```

I have a list in my HTML that has to show the item value_en or value_it based on the App config settings.

So let's say my variable `LANG_CODE` stores the language from the settings, so I think I should make a list with a dynamic variable.

Also my `LANG_CODE` is actually visible only thru a filter so it would be like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="sub_cat in categorie">
    <h2>{{sub_cat.value+'_'+[LANG_CODE | translate]}}</h2>
</li>
```

Where if I do `{{LANG_CODE | translate}}` it shows either `it` or `en`

Comment: `{{ sub_cat['value_' + (LANG_CODE | translate)] }}`

Comment: That's great @JBNizet!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct way:

```
{{ sub_cat['value_' + (LANG_CODE | translate)] }}
```